Sun's lens flare
At what degree of the sun's altitude/hight does it's lens flare appear? (At sea level and without any external influences).
I'm trying to develop a game and I want to add lens flare to the sun. My problem is that when the sun is below the horizon, the lens flare is still visible, so I want to make it hidden so that the sun becomes at the altitude at which the lens fare appears.

Lens flare is the inner reflection and bouncing of light in the lens that is strong enough to project (normally unwanted) light at the wrong places to the film or sensor.
So lens flare is there every time there is a to strong light source that casts light into the lens. So its not just the sun, but also bright lights in the night and so on.
The angle is probably not predicable in general but you can probably approximate it. E.g. when strong light gets to the front lens (so for computer graphics: the light source can see the front lens element) then a lens flare can occur.
So to get to the special point in your question: If the sun is below the horizon it cannot see the lens, so no lens flare would be occur.
Lens hoods helping with avoiding this to a certain point. (better on fixed focal lengths lenses, since there the angle of the view frustum is fix. and worse on zoom lenses, where the lens hood only works best at the shortest focal length.)

Personal opinion: When I play a game, I am normally a person/creature that sees with it's own eyes and eyes don't have a lens flare. There is even a meme that jokes around that video game characters eyes are camera lenses.
So my recommendation: if the stuff you want to show on screen is seen by the characters own eyes, then don't use lens flares, glitch filters and stuff like that. If it is seen by some kind of lens, then do build in such effects.
Bonus points if there is a switch between own eyes to a camera (like a game about photography where you first see all raw with your eyes and then you take the camera and look thru it, so all the physically properties of light goes thru a system of glass lenses takes place.)

Not all zoom lenses only have the best hood coverage at the widest focal length. The Canon EF 24-70mm f/2.8 (original) is retrofocus throughout its entire zoom range. The inner barrel is most extended at 24mm and most recessed at 70mm. The hood attaches to the main barrel which does not move. Thus the petals of the hood are further in front of the recessed front element at 70mm and closer to the extended front element at 24mm.

Assuming the camera has a clear view to the horizon or any place in the sky above the horizon, when the sun is above the horizon it can cause lens flare under the right conditions. Those conditions include:

The angle of view of the lens and the angle between the sun and the lens' center axis.
The lens' optical formula, antireflective coatings, hood (or lack thereof), etc.
The exposure settings. (Please see example below)

Flare is always there to one degree or another any time a bright light source is within view of the lens' front surface. Under what we would typically call normal exposure conditions, a lot of that flare isn't bright enough to emerge from the noise floor. However, if we expose bright enough that same flare can be quite noticeable.
Here's an image of the Moon and Jupiter.

Here's another image of the moon and Jupiter.

It's taken on the same night with the same camera, lens, settings, etc. except that the second image is exposed 12 stops brighter. It's also rotated about 90° from the first image and cropped slightly differently.
The flare visible in the second image was also there in the first image, it was just too dim with the lower exposure to be seen in the image, just the same as the moons of Jupiter and brighter stars that can be seen in the second image aren't visible in the first because they are too dim for the camera to sense them at the lower exposure level.
